# Allocate Table seating to Guests

Tags: algorithm

[image: Please look this table]
These are the tables in a wedding reception, i want to reserve these tables for diffrent groups, but it should be optimum.

I want to calculate the optimal minimum seat allocation for guests.

> NB :  a group can take more than one table at a time. but sharing of a
> table between teams is not allowed for example, if a group of 6
> persons wants sit in the tables, how we can calculate the optimal
> seating

Comment: _"it should be optimum"_. How are you defining optimality?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, don't waste the seats. we need to accomodate maximum number of people

Answer (score 0):

your question is probably NP-complete.
Let it be 1 team with K persons and N tables, the optimal solution is equivalent to the subset sum problem -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Because if you had a solution of the subset sum problem is also a optimal solution in that case.